# Shopify + GraphQL (gem: shopify_app / shopify_api)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am new to building shopify applications, and am a bit confused regarding GraphQL.

**Currently:**

I have built a super simple Shopify application using the shopify_app gem. The application has some webhooks associated with orders. When a shop creates an order, I receive the JSON from the order, run a job in my code and submit the data I want to my local database.

**What I am trying to do:**

I need to access all orders from a shopify store that installs my application, and store all orders for that store. I would want to fetch all orders every 4-months or so. Shopify gave my application permission to fetch all orders.

**My issue/question:**

It appears the best course of action here is to use GraphQL. What I am confused with is do I need to use the shopify_api gem in addition to the shopify_app gem to get GraphQL to work?

Comment: shopify_api gem is already part of shopify_app gem, [this] (https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/blob/master/docs/graphql.md) might help, remember any request you do needs to be wrapped in `with_shopify_session` block or you need to manually set the session before read/write from any shop. Good luck!

Comment: Karim - thank you. I ended up figuring it out - and should have posted the answer. But thank you (upvote given)

Comment: I'm glad you figure it out! Thanks for the upvote :)